# backup script in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am new in shell script.Will you please suggest how to write backup shell script. I am having following formated data in target directory.

`StoreID_date_time.zip`

Like:

```
-rw------- 1 rupesh ldapusers  8267310 Mar 22 12:00 44_22032014_115629.zip

-rw------- 1 rupesh ldapusers  8269938 Mar 22 12:07 44_22032014_120013.zip

-rw------- 1 rupesh ldapusers  8267110 Mar 22 12:14 44_22032014_120704.zip

-rw------- 1 rupesh ldapusers  8254223 Mar 22 14:25 45_22032014_142155.zip

-rw------- 1 rupesh ldapusers  7871060 Mar 22 12:11 48_22032014_120813.zip

-rw------- 1 rupesh ldapusers  8314418 Mar 22 12:22 48_22032014_121038.zip

-rw------- 1 rupesh ldapusers  8254699 Mar 24 12:13 49_22032014_145338.zip
```

Now I want to backup files with following way:

Backup directory : `/backup/date/storeid/zip` files of that store

like:

```
/backup/22032014/44/44_22032014_115629.zip,44_22032014_120013.zip...so on

/backup/22032014/45/45_22032014_142155.zip

/backup/22032014/48/48_22032014_120813.zip,48_22032014_121038.zip

/backup/22032014/49/49_22032014_145338.zip
```

for next day `/backup/23032014/respective_storeIDfolder&files`

Please give some hint or code example so I can move foreword.

Answer (score 1):

I have coded in bare minimum steps without doing a real check but verified it. It works fine with some dummy files I created on my box :)

```
#!/bin/bash


for i in $(find * -type f -iname '*.zip' )
do
     echo "Zip file :  "$i
     store_id=$(echo $i | cut -d "_" -f 1  );
     timestamp=$(echo $i | cut -d "_" -f 2  );
     echo Store id = ${store_id}
     # I am assuming all these directories here will be of teh same pattern name. Else put a numeric check down.
     mkdir -p /backup/${timestamp}/${store_id}
     cp -f $i /backup/${timestamp}/${store_id}/
done;
```

Comment: It is perfectly working. Thank you. I did some changes & now backup path becomes /backup/store_id/timestamp. Now I want each store_id contain only recent three dates files like: /backup/44/21032014,22032014,23032014 if 24032014 comes remove 21032014 so.on

Comment: Great. You need to write a logic for this. cd into the store_id directory. sort the filenames in descending order and except the first three elements/files , delete all. Simple ! You may also want to mark this answer as answered.

Comment: I need to be scripted.